# Wordpress Theme Settings Page

Tags: theme-options

I'm having a hard time getting my 'Hello World' to display on the theme page I created. It all at least appears to be correct (but obviously isn't) - what am I missing here?

```
// Add Theme Options to menu

function add_theme_menu_item() {

add_theme_page("Theme Panel", "Theme Panel", "manage_options", "theme-panel", "initialize_theme_options", null, 99);

}

add_action("admin_menu", "add_theme_menu_item");

 /**
 * Initializes the theme options page by registering the Sections,
  * Fields, and Settings.
 *
 * This function is registered with the 'admin_init' hook.
 */

 function initialize_theme_options() {

// First, we register a section. This is necessary since all future options must belong to one.

add_settings_section(

    // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
    'main_settings_section',

    // Title to be displayed on the administration page
    'Main Theme Options',

    // Callback used to render the description of the section

    'main_settings_callback', 

    // Page

    'theme-panel'

);

} 

add_action('admin_init', 'initialize_theme_options');

 // end initialize_theme_options

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *
* Section Callbacks
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

/**
* This function provides a simple description for the General Options page. 
*
* It is called from the 'initialize_theme_options' function by being passed as a parameter
* in the add_settings_section function.
*/

function main_settings_callback() {

  echo 'Hello world.';

} 
// end main_settings_callback
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
add_theme_page("Theme Panel", "Theme Panel", "manage_options", "theme-panel", "initialize_theme_options", null, 99);
```

The last two parameters shouldn't be there. Check this function in codex [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_page).

EDIT:

What's more, the last parameter (which should be there) `initialize_theme_options` is wrong too, because it should be a callback to a function which would output a content. So for example your `main_settings_callback` function.

SECOND EDIT:

It doesn't work you probably because in the call of `add_settings_section` function you pass in the last parameter `theme-panel` and this page probably doesn't exist. Am I right? Try to replace this parameter for example with `general` and it'll output at the main Setting page.

Comment: Is there any reason why my init theme option wouldn't trigger 'add_settings_section' which has a callback of main_settings_callback? main_settings being what would output the content?

Comment: Check my second edit please.

Comment: Hmm, you're right on that one. I'm wondering why I am unable to pass the theme page (with a slug of theme-panel) to the add _settings_function page parameter. It does in fact exist (the Theme Panel page), it's just blank. I had assumed by adding an additional page (via add_theme_page) that I could then pass the slug of this page to add_settings_section and it would work. Am I approaching this in the wrong manner?  Thanks for your feedback on this by the way, much appreciated.

Comment: Ah, I see what I'm doing wrong. The add_theme_page has a $menu_slug parameter NOT a $page_slug paramater. Duh.         But wait, this is what I was basing my assumption on: '$page
(string) (required) The menu page on which to display this section. Should match $menu_slug from Function Reference/add theme page' from: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_settings_sections

```
function initialize_theme_options() {

// First, we register a section. This is necessary since all future options must belong to one.

add_settings_section(

    // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
    'main_settings_section',

    // Title to be displayed on the administration page
    'Main Theme Options',

    // Callback used to render the description of the section

    'main_settings_callback', 

    // Page

    'theme-panel'

);

do_settings_sections('theme-panel');

}
```